# Como identifico que radio buttons fue seleccionado de cada grupo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy realizando una aplicación donde se generan grupos de Radio Buttons cuyos nombres y valores depende de un json.  Pero, tengo un detalle, si por ejemplo se generan 3 grupos de radio buttons con 3 opciones cada uno, yo lo que quiero es saber que radio buttons fue seleccionado de cada grupo. Alguna sugerencia de como puedo hacerlo
Estos pueden ser 2 grupos, 10 grupos, etc.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Vista_producto.this);
                        int id = R.layout.botones;

                        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(id, null, false);
                        TextView textView = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                        textView.setText(std_name);
                        RadioGroupt = (RadioGroup) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);
                        //LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
                        //RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                (int)(55*density),
                                (int)(45*density));
                        int margin = (int)(6*density);
                        params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);

                        i= i + 1;
                        layout.addView(linearLayout);
                        String std_item = jsonObject1.getString("std_item");

                        JSONObject js6 = new JSONObject(std_item);
                        int j = 0;
                        Iterator<String> keys1 = js6.keys();
                        while (keys1.hasNext()) {
                            String key1 = keys1.next();
                            Log.i("Parser", "objeto : " + key1);
                            JSONObject ke = js6.getJSONObject(key1);
                            String std_item_name = ke.getString("std_item_name");
                            Rboton = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
                            Rboton.setText(std_item_name);
                            Rboton.setId(j);
                            RadioGroupt.addView(Rboton);
                            //Rboton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            Rboton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.borde);
                            //Rboton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.boton_p);

              Rboton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rb_background_lluvia);
                            Rboton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            Rboton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            Rboton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ps no se si entiendo bien, pero creo que podrias generarle un id a cada radio que se va generando conforme el grupo, es decir del primer grupo los id serian: idrgp1, idrgp2 y que al seleccionarlo guarde ese id en algun lado ya sea una tabla sqlite. no se si me hice entender.

Answer (score 0):

podrias ponerle tags a tus botones de la siguiente manera

Ejemplo de un botón

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/buttonTag"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:text="Hola"/>
```

En tu clase Java le agregas un tag de la siguiente manera

```
Button buttonTag = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTag);
// set tag
button.setTag("boton_hola);
```

Y obtienes el tag de la siguiente manera

```
String tag = (String) buttonTag.getTag();
```

Por lo que veo solo deberias agregar el tag, y luego con la ultima linea obtener el tag que seria el id que tu deberias asignarle para diferenciar los botones y de esta manera saber cual es cual. Saludos.

Comment: Creo que no me explique bien. Ya cada radio button tiene su id. Mi problema es, si por ejemplo se generan 3 grupos de radio buttons con 3 opciones cada uno, yo lo que quiero es saber que radio buttons fue seleccionado de cada grupo. 
Es importante recalcar que pueden ser 2 grupos, 10 grupos, etc, por lo que necesito una función global que independientemente del número de grupos y opciones pueda revisarlos.

Comment: Mmmm, podrias crear el onclick a cada boton y cuando sean seleccionados llamar a una funcion que sea una lista que guarde tofo lo que se ha seleccionado

Comment: gracias, ya se puede seleccionar cada radio button  con el onclick, pero no se como implementarlo con la lista. Al hacer clic en uno, debo guardar la combinacion de los 3 (en el caso en que sean 3) porque con esa combinacion es que busco en la base de datos